# ERROR: Cannot find module '../constants.js' - if pm2 is run as start script on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, pm2

While migrating to Azure App Service on **Linux**, my app fails to start while throwing:

```
> NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../constants.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/pm2:11:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --ignore './public' server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pm2": "^3.3.1"
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.6",
  }
}
```

App Service has pm2 installed globally, and if I comment out my start script it will pick my server.js automatically which works, but I need to get my own start script working to set some ENV vars.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: If you're executing this from site/wwwroot/, then .../ means you're looking for a file in the site folder. Have you tried ./constants.js? What if you move server.js into your source code folder (e.g. src/server.js)?

Comment: I suggest that you need to change these relative path like `../constants.js` to the absolute path like `D:/home/site/wwwroot/constants.js`, because the relative path is based on the path of IIS started up iis-node on Azure App Service.

Comment: Thanks, @MitchStewart `../constants.js` is a dependency of pm2, so I don't have how to move it. @Peter Pan - thanks, however I'm on a Linux instance and as mentioned constants.js is a dep. of pm2.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with constants but in another node module.

1. i deleted node_modules and lock file.
2. started to reinstall this and canch new issue, the problem was the lack
   of free space: "ENOSPC: no space left on device, write"
3. fixed it,
   and now i am happy ^)